# How to determine why some files aren't fully downloading

Tags: java, stream

I'm using this code to download files:

```
    try{
        File remoteFile = new File(matcher.group());
        file = new File(destinationPath+"."+remoteFile.getExtension());

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(i);
        }
        bos.flush();
        bis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "    - Unable to download remote file({0}): {1} ", new Object[] { url.toString(), e.getMessage() });
        file.delete();
        return false;
    }
```

There are instances where the full file doesn't download.  I do not know the cause and am wondering what my options are to attempt to determine the cause.  I can download the files manually in my browser.  Only about 5% of the files are failing to download.  So far I haven't noticed any patterns in the types of files that are failing.

I'm wondering if there's something I can do, perhaps some debug mode or something where I can force the stream to complain and give me details when the connection is cut.

**update:** This is wrapping with exception handling, but I haven't seen anything.  It could just be a result of timing though, that I haven't been watching it when the error occurs.

Comment: No exception is thrown?

Comment: you should always close your resources in finally block, or in java 7 with new try feature

Comment: @nachokk Can you link me to an example?  I'm not sure in this scenario I understand why `finally` would be useful.